# Use change tracking in StoredProcedure only if is On for table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, change-tracking

I want to create an SP that will get data from ChangeTracking only if it is enabled for a given table.

In SP I have:

```
DECLARE @CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED BIT;
SELECT @CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED = is_track_columns_updated_on FROM sys.change_tracking_tables WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable')
if @CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED = 1
begin
    insert into @IDS select CT.[ID_MY_TABLE] FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [MyTable], @last_change_version) as CT
end
```

But when I try to create procedure I have an error:

```
Change tracking is not enabled on table 'MyTable'.
```

What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: It very rare to be able to right good maintainable stored procedures when you're effectively saying they have to work against an unknown schema. Why isn't it set in stone whether or not those tables have change tracking enabled? If you actually want to support different schemas, I'd recommend looking at other tooling, not T-SQL control flow, to maintain different versions of objects affected by the different schemas.

Comment: Do you get an error when you *compile* or when you *execute* the procedure? If first, then the problem is that sql server probably early binds some stuff, you need to change to dynamic sql the parts that rans CHANGETABLE code. If second, then there's a bug in your code, OR it can be that SQL Server does some early bindings anyway, in which case, it should also help to convert that part to dynamic sql. If it still bugs after dynamic sql, then perhaps you have a bug after all, in the code that checks if table is being tracked :D

Comment: When compline, I can't create new stored procedure because of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way the object binding works, the server is compiling the whole batch and failing before it even runs.

While you could use deferred object resolution for non-existent tables, this doesn't work if the table exists but change tracking is off.

You have two options:

- Use dynamic SQL. Less maintainable because refactoring can't see it, but you can keep it in one procedure.

```sql
DECLARE @CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED BIT;
SELECT @CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED = ct.is_track_columns_updated_on
FROM sys.change_tracking_tables ct
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = ct.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.name = N'MyTable'
  AND s.name = N'dbo';

IF @CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT @IDS (ColumnsHere)
    EXEC sp_executesql N'
    SELECT CT.ID_MY_TABLE
    FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [MyTable], @last_change_version) as CT;
';
END;
```

- Use another stored procedure. More maintainable, I would recommend this.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetChangeTracking_MyTable
  @last_change_version bigint
AS

SELECT CT.ID_MY_TABLE
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [MyTable], @last_change_version) as CT;
```

```sql
DECLARE @CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED BIT;
SELECT @CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED = ct.is_track_columns_updated_on
FROM sys.change_tracking_tables ct
JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = ct.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.name = N'MyTable'
  AND s.name = N'dbo';

IF @CHANGE_TRACKING_ENABLED = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT @IDS (ColumnsHere)
    EXEC dbo.GetChangeTracking_MyTable @last_change_version;
END;
```